# AsyncHTTPClient with https auth proxy

Tags: python, proxy, tornado

I am trying to configure AsyncHTTPClient with auth proxy to access https websites. Is it possible to do with authenticated proxy?

```
from tornado import httpclient, ioloop

config = {
    'proxy_host': proxy_host,
    'proxy_port': proxy_post,
    "proxy_username": proxy_username,
    "proxy_password": proxy_password
}


httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient.configure("tornado.curl_httpclient.CurlAsyncHTTPClient")

def handle_request(response):
    if response.error:
        print("Error:", response.error)
    else:
        print(response.body)
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().stop()

http_client = httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
http_client.fetch("https://twitter.com/",
    handle_request, **config)
ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

I get these errors after running the code above

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Adam\Anaconda3\envs\sizeer\lib\site-packages\tornado\curl_httpclient.py", line 130, in _handle_socket
    self.io_loop.add_handler(fd, self._handle_events, ioloop_event)
  File "C:\Users\Adam\Anaconda3\envs\sizeer\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 103, in add_handler
    self.asyncio_loop.add_writer(fd, self._handle_events, fd, IOLoop.WRITE)
  File "C:\Users\Adam\Anaconda3\envs\sizeer\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 507, in add_writer
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Adam\Anaconda3\envs\sizeer\lib\site-packages\tornado\curl_httpclient.py", line 130, in _handle_socket
    self.io_loop.add_handler(fd, self._handle_events, ioloop_event)
  File "C:\Users\Adam\Anaconda3\envs\sizeer\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 97, in add_handler
    raise ValueError("fd %s added twice" % fd)
ValueError: fd 700 added twice
ERROR:asyncio:Future exception was never retrieved
future: <Future finished exception=HTTP 599: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate>
tornado.curl_httpclient.CurlError: HTTP 599: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Process finished with exit code -1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the only problem here, but the NotImplementedError is because Python 3.8 on Windows uses a different event loop implementation that is incompatible with Tornado. You need to add `asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())` to the beginning of your main file/function.

I suspect you may also need to use the `ca_certs` argument to tell `libcurl` where to find the trusted root certificates for your proxy.

Comment: What if i wanted to make several requests at one time? Do i have to generate ca_certs before i want to send all the requests? What's more it's not my own proxy server, the only thing i get is the ip with username and password.

Comment: And is it possible to generate ca_certs for my proxy if i do not own the server? Do you recommend some way of doing it?

Comment: Where did its certificates come from? If they're using the standard web trust roots I thought they'd be picked up automatically, but maybe you have to do something special on windows (i don't develop on windows). If they're self-signed then maybe you use the site's certificate itself as the CA cert? I'm not sure how exactly that works. You could also pass `validate_cert=False` to turn off the CA verification at some expense of security.

Comment: ```validate_cert=False``` actually worked, i tried to generate certificates myself, but it didn't worked that way because it's not local server. What can it lead to when i set validate_cert to False?

Comment: With validate_cert=False, you have no proof that you're connected to the proxy that you think you are (you're vulnerable to MITM attacks)